# RecyclerView. CardView. Обработчик нажатия

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть 3 `RecyclerView`. В каждый загружается свой `JSON`. Все это в одном `activity`. Как мне, после клика на карточку, вывести данные в новом `activity`, но в каждой карточке свои данные? (думаю, что даже придется подгрузить свой `JSON` и распарсить на 3-5 `RecyclerView`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем всё использовать в одном activity? Можно сделать классы и обращаться к ним. У всех активити есть предок `Context`. Можно с ним сделать, сперва посоветую разгрузить код, далее...

Скорее всего, у вас есть класс коллекции, который сохраняет в себя значения из JSON, полученные каким-то образом.

Далее. Есть адаптеры, куда вы передаете все значения из этого класса коллекции. В адаптере есть метод `View()`, который отвечает за нажатие на любую колонку. Напишите в этом адаптере метод для динамического заполнения данных.

Вот пример адаптера. Там есть слушатели, в которые необходимо добавить динамические действия, которые вы будете посылать через intent-объекты в новый activity, из которого впоследствии будете их извлекать.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {
    Context c;
    ArrayList<String> players;
    public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> players) {
        this.c = c;
        this.players = players;
    }
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model,parent,false);
        MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.nameTxt.setText(players.get(position));
        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int pos) {
                Toast.makeText(c,players.get(pos),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return players.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: отформатируйте и структурируйте ответ.

Comment: Спс. В одном активити - мы видим 3 горизонтальных RecyclerView(это все работает вижу заполненные карточки). вопрос точнее- если брать ID с базы данных они(ID) могут повторятся так как 3 разные таблицы(MySQL). не попутает ли адаптер ID при клике на cardView.

Comment: Sublihim спс. сейчас попытаюсь разобраться в вашем примере

Comment: Нет как Id может  поворяться у каждой строчки уникальное айди должно быть и для каждого RecyclerView  должн быть свой адаптер и свой Класс коллекция .

Comment: @РахимБыкаев "пример не мой, я просто разместил объяву"

Comment: id присваивается автоматически при добавлении строчки в таблицу mySql начинается с единицы (таблицы 3 штуки) из каждой таблицы в свой RecyclerView через один адаптер, но по очереди. то есть заполняться первый RecyclerView потом скачивается второй Json используя тот же адаптер. после повторяю на третьем.

Comment: думаю что нужно как то слушать карточки и в каждой карточке находить  String содержащий в себе urlAddress пришедший с Json-ом (далее парсить urlAddress- который был в каждой карточке и выводить это в другом активити).

Comment: Ну код за тебя писать не буду но ответ мой тебе поможет .Если ответ устроил жми вверх помечай как правильный если устраивает

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
                  //  Toast.makeText(c,players.get(pos),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(c, holder.nametxt.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

Comment: мой опасения были напрасны, вот так проверил имена не путает(что то я не допонимаю),  спс

Comment: У вас каждый RecyclerView пишется отдельыным адаптером

Comment: всем спасибо. понял

Comment: Незачто )тебе вбщето я ответил обидно когда так поступают